# Remove select characters from xml tags using regex

Tags: python, regex, xml

I am trying to remove only select characters from xml tags + any digit that follows + the proceeding `:` .. for example:
`<ns2:projectArea alias=` should look like `<projectArea alias=`
and `<ns9:name>` should look like `<name>`

Basically, the digit will be random (anything from 1-9) and there will always be a proceeding `:` that must be deleted.

What I have so far is:

```
import argparse
import re

# Initiates argument
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("--input", "-i", help="Set the input xml to clean up")
parser.add_argument("--output", "-o", help="Set the output xml location")

args = parser.parse_args()
inputfile = args.input
outputfile = args.output
if args.input:
  print("inputfile location is %s" % args.input)
if args.output:
  print("outputfile location is %s" % args.output)
# End argument

text = re.sub('<[^<]+>', "", open(inputfile).read())
with open(outputfile, "w") as f:
    f.write(text)
```

This piece of the code is the issue: `'<[^<]+>'`
It deletes entire tags, so if i need to search text later on,  basically have to search plain text rather than by tags.

What can I replace `'<[^<]+>'` with that will delete `ns` + the following number (whatever number it may be) + the `:` that follows it?

Comment: `/[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]:` However this is assuming you only want to search for one digit

Comment: Try: [`(?<=<)ns[0-9]+:(?=[^>]*?>)`](https://regex101.com/r/Zt4OE3/1)

Comment: Stop trying to parse XML/HTML with regular expressions, and use a DOM parser instead. (And the *select characters* are called a namespace.)

Comment: [`r'<([^:]+):.*?>'`](https://regex101.com/r/WIjqUW/1) or a parser that allows to kill namespaces before dumping it again

Comment: @Matt.G that actually worked almost perfectly.. but, the end tag with ```/``` does not get deleted unless I add it to the stanza, such as:  ```(?<=<)/ns[0-9]+:(?=[^>]*?>)``` Is there a way to make it delete the ```/ns...``` if it exists?

Comment: @Matt.G actually, to better phrase my question, I am trying to figure out the logic for making it delete both beginning and end tags.

Answer (score 1):

It might be happening because of the regex expression. Try using this regex expression instead:

```
   text = re.sub('^<[a-zA-Z0-9]+:','<',open(inputfile).read())
```

Answer (score 0):

This works :

Find  `r"<(?:(?:(/?)\w+[1-9]:(\w+\s*/?))|(?:\w+[1-9]:(\w+\s+(?:\"[\S\s]*?\"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]?)+\s*/?)))>"`
Replace `<$1$2$3>`

https://regex101.com/r/yRhMI9/1

Readable version :

```
 <
 (?:
      (?:
           ( /? )                        # (1)
           \w+ [1-9] :
           ( \w+ \s* /? )                # (2)
      )
   |  (?:
           \w+ [1-9] :
           (                             # (3 start)
                \w+ \s+ 
                (?: " [\S\s]*? " | ' [\S\s]*? ' | [^>]? )+
                \s* /?
           )                             # (3 end)
      )
 )
 >
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex: `(?:(?<=<)|(?<=<\/))(ns[0-9]+:)(?=[^>]*?>)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zt4OE3/3)